# Angular UI-Grid Spanned Column header

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid that has spanned column headers and has some columns that are pinned either left or right.

All is working fine with this apart from the ui-grid cells borders not lining up the further you scroll across.

See demo [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEHt06v2pajoJWTYzopA?p=preview)

this is my header template

```
<div role="rowgroup"
 class="ui-grid-header">
<div class="ui-grid-top-panel">
    <div class="ui-grid-header-viewport">
        <div class="ui-grid-header-canvas">
            <div class="ui-grid-header-cell-wrapper" style="display: block;"
                 ng-style="colContainer.headerCellWrapperStyle()">
                <div role="row"
                     class="ui-grid-header-cell-row" >
                    <div class="ui-grid-header-cell ui-grid-clearfix ui-grid-category" ng-repeat="cat in grid.options.category"
                         style="text-align: center" ng-if="cat.visible && (colContainer.renderedColumns | filter:{ colDef:{category: cat.name} }).length > 0 && cat.pinned === colContainer.name">
                        <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" style="display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid;border-bottom-color: #d4d4d4;" ng-class="{'category-pinned-left': cat.pinned ==='left'}"  >&nbsp;{{cat.displayName}}&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-cell ui-grid-clearfix"
                             ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns | filter:{ colDef:{category: cat.name} }"
                             ui-grid-header-cell
                             col="col"
                             render-index="$index">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.